# Iterate Multidimensional Numpy Array and Divide

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Say you have a multidimensional Numpy array of shape (100,3). For example, here's the first 5 rows (head):

```
array([[ 255.16 ,  336.7  , 2479.9  ],
   [ 249.98 ,  329.48 , 2451.32 ],
   [ 247.76 ,  325.9  , 2422.52 ],
   [ 245.22 ,  325.78 , 2395.02 ],
   [ 248.125,  330.38 , 2435.31 ]])
```

How would you iterate over each row by and divide by the previous row using numpy.  For example, 249.98 / 255.16. Then 247.76 / 249.98.

And doing this over each column, say, we completed first column and now we want to do the second column, 329.48 / 336.7.  Then 325.9 / 329.48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this assuming your array is called `matrix`:

```
>>> np.array([matrix[i+1]/matrix[i] for i in range(matrix.shape[0]-1)])
array([[0.97969901, 0.97855658, 0.98847534],
       [0.99111929, 0.98913439, 0.98825123],
       [0.98974814, 0.99963179, 0.98864818],
       [1.01184651, 1.01411996, 1.01682241]])
```